# When i try to create user rails says ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, actionview

---

*Updated:*
**Problem solved**
I just had to put `protect_from_forgery` in the `Users` controller. Thanks to all.

---

Rails 4.0.2
When I try to create a new record in the `users` table i get this message in browser:

```
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in UsersController#create
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken
```

But it happens in Chrome(32.0.1700.107) and Opera(12.16) browsers. In Firefox(27.0.1) and IE 10.0.13 all works fine. Maybe it does not matter, but i have to say that also i use has_secure_password(bcrypt_ruby).

Rails Log:

```
...
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-19 10:26:05 +0400
Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"93jpgxCSY3XzZkIJKraOodyObBoaPoPMVz3RiOVBL10=", "user"=>{"name"=>"", "surname"=>"", "patronymic"=>"", "email"=>"", "address"=>"", "phone"=>"", "phone2"=>"", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Создать пользователя"}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 2ms

ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken):
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:163:in `handle_unverified_request'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:170:in `handle_unverified_request'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:177:in `verify_authenticity_token'
...
```

View file `users/new.html.slim`:

```
= stylesheet_link_tag 'users'
.new_user_container
  = form_for @user do |f|
    = f.label "Имя"
    br
    = f.text_field :name
    br
    = f.label "Фамилия"
    br
    = f.text_field :surname
    br
    = f.label "Отчество"
    br
    = f.text_field :patronymic
    br
    = f.label "Пароль"
    br
    = f.text_field :password
    br
    = f.label "Подтверждение пароля"
    br
    = f.text_field :password_confirmation
    br
    br
    = f.submit "Создать пользователя"
```

Comment: to you have `  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>` this in your application.html.erb?

Comment: @devanand Yes, I do. But after removing of this line I get same error=(

Comment: maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20875591/actioncontrollerinvalidauthenticitytoken-in-registrationscontrollercreate?rq=1

Comment: try add this on `application_controller.rb` `protect_from_forgery with: :null_session`

Comment: or you can skip this filter `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token`

Comment: @devanand Thank you. I wrote `protect_from_forgery except: :create` and this helped. But i believe this wrong and dangerous way.

Comment: yes you are right. it may works but it's not a good way because dangerous

Comment: @Monk_Code I have tried `protect_from_forgery except: :create` already and this works. Thank you. If this is bug of the Rails then i have no way to solve it. Only the turning off of this function. It's sad.

Comment: this is no bug, it feature, read [this](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb#L162) and [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection/ClassMethods.html)

Comment: @Monk_Code In other words it means that it's a normal behaviour when 2 browsers from 4 does not supported. If so then i can only block this feature. Right?

Comment: Yes. Different behavior browser normal thing(IMHO).

Comment: @Monk_Code @devanand hmm.. Oh my dog. It seems I had deceived myself. Just I had to place `protect_from_forgery` without any options in the controller `Users`.

Answer (score 7):

I just had to put `protect_from_forgery` in the Users controller. Thanks to all.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery

  def index
    #@users = User.all.includes(:roles)
    @users = User.all
  end
  def show

  end
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end
  def create
    @user = User.new user_params
    puts @user.errors.inspect
    if @user.save
      flash[:notice] = "Пользователь удачно создан"
      redirect_to :users
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Пользователь не создан"
      render file: :'users/user_error'
    end
    flash["notice"] = "Test notice"
    #redirect_to :users
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem. This only happens in Chrome browser. But my problem lies in that I forbid the Cookies in Chrome's `Content Settings`. So just enable it, or select `Clear on quit` if you must forbid this.

NOTE: This setting is brought from the Chrome browser on another device of mine. If you login Chrome with your Google account, Chrome will synchronize your settings between devices. So it may be hard to be aware of the problem.

Hope this can help other people who meet this problem.