# InvalidAuthenticityToken in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I recently added a piece of code to my ApplicationController to set the timezone of the current block to the one specified by the user.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  around_action :set_time_zone, if: :current_user
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  private

  def set_time_zone(&block)
    Time.use_zone(current_user.time_zone, &block)
  end
end
```

For some reason when I try to sign in i get a

```
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in Devise::SessionsController#create
```

If i remove

```
around_action :set_time_zone, if: :current_user
```

I can sign in and if i add it back after I sign in, everything works as expected.

Any ideas?

Comment: I believe you need to require jquery_ujs in application.js
//= require jquery_ujs

Comment: @Rafal jquery_ujs is already required!

Comment: ok, and do you have <%= csrf_meta_tags %> tag in your application.rb ?

Comment: @Rafal yes i do! It seems its a problem with the Devise controllers only

Comment: ok then you need to change it to protect_from_forgery with: :null_session

Comment: See this answer for reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20875591/actioncontrollerinvalidauthenticitytoken-in-registrationscontrollercreate

Comment: @Rafal thanks for the link, basically all that change does is not show the exception anymore but the error still exists

Comment: So try moving the protect_from_forgery before your around_filter, it might solve it based on the answers from the other question

Comment: @Rafal that fixed it...thank you very much

Answer (score 4):

[This page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20875591/actioncontrollerinvalidauthenticitytoken-in-registrationscontrollercreate/20875842#20875842) has good info on the problem, but I was weirdly able to fix this in Rails 5 by putting `protect_from_forgery` *above* the `around_action/filter`.  Hope it helps!

Comment: This saved me almost 3.5 years later.  I had a before_action setting context for Sentry.  I had it above the protect_from_forgery call...which was causing InvalidAuthenticityToken  errors just after log in.