# Can't verify CSRF token authenticity Rails/React

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, csrf, protect-from-forgery

I have a react component in my rails app where I'm trying to use `fetch()` to send a *POST* to my rails app hosted on localhost, this gives me the error:

```
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken):
```

I'm using devise gem to handle `user/registrations` and `logins`.

I have tried to remove `protect_from_forgery with: :exception`

Here is the code for my fetch,

```
this.state.ids.sub_id});
  fetch(POST_PATH, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: body  
  }).then(res => res.json()).then(console.log);
```

How can I get the csrf token and send it through the form so that it will pass? 
Ideally I would like to just send it through the headers but I have no idea how to access the token.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The simplest way to do this, if you are merely embedding a react component in your Rails view, is to retrieve the csrf token from your rails view and then pass it as a header in your fetch api call.

You can get the csrf token by doing something like this:

```
const csrf = document.querySelector("meta[name='csrf-token']").getAttribute("content");
```

And then you just pass it as a header in your fetch call:

`...
headers: {
   'Content-Type': 'application/json',
   'X-CSRF-Token': csrf
 },
...`

I normally don't use fetch, so not too sure about the exact syntax, but this should help guide you.

Comment: But don't they now have per form csrf tokens in rails 5 and later?  Does this still work with that?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks! I ended up with this as a working solution:
In the view that renders my react component

```
<% csrf_token = form_authenticity_token %>

<%= react_component('ExerciseDisplay', {
  program: @program.subprograms.first.exercises, ids: {sub_id: @program.subprograms.first.id, team_id: @team.id, token: csrf_token}
}) %>
```

I passed the token into state, then accessed it via fetch:

```
  fetch(POST_PATH, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-CSRF-Token': this.state.ids.token
      },
      body: body  
}).then(res => res.json()).then(console.log);
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `form` element, add a `authenticity_token`:

```html
<input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value={csrf}/>
```

Set the value as per the below:

```js
const csrf = document.querySelector("meta[name='csrf-token']").getAttribute("content");
```

Answer (score -2):

I too faced the same issue when using **rails 5.2** and i was able to fix this issue by adding

`protect_from_forgery with: :null_session`  in **application_controller.rb** [i got this from here,please refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20875842/5706413)

Comment: This seems like a security risk doesnt it?

Comment: @SamuelFaure i am not an expert in this maybe ur right,please refer the link attached