# Logging out returns Can't verify CSRF token authenticity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, csrf

I am able to login and logout most of the time, but sometimes during logging out I am returned with this error as stated below and I am not logged out.

```
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.
User excluded error: #<ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken: ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken>
```

It doesn't happen always that I am not able to logout but when I am not able to logout above is the error which I get. I read about it this is what I have done so far. I am using vuejs on my front end and rails on the backend. I am using rails version 5.1.

application_controller.rb

```
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
```

application.html.erb

```
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

this is the axios request I am making to logout the user

index.vue

```
logout() {
 this.$axios.delete('/users/sign_out').then(function(response) {
  console.log("Logged out")
 });
}
```

Please help me resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add the csrf_meta_tags to the request

In your case, the csrf_meta_tags in application.html.erb is not re-rendered.

Comment: Here if found something which can be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54808071/cant-verify-csrf-token-authenticity-rails-react

Comment: isnt csrf required only during login request?

Comment: CSRF token is required for every non-GET request (the default behavior).

Comment: @JagdeepSingh can you help me with how can I add the csrf token with the request.

Comment: Maybe this can be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22063612/adding-csrftoken-to-ajax-request