# rails 4 resets session on every request in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, production, ruby-on-rails-4.2, ruby-2.2

I am implementing web app using rails 4.2.0 and ruby 2.2.0 and facing problem that any time request in done new session is set. In that case I cannot save anything to session since it's gone. Also that leads to situation that authenticity token cannot be checked.

For testing purpose forgery protection is disabled in `ApplicationController`, so that's not reason why session is reset.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  #protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token `
end
```

I am using active record store to save session, but same happens for cookie store:

```
MyApp::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store, :key => '_myapp_session', domain: :all, tld_length: 2
```

Every time request is done new entry to `sessions` table is inserted with new `sessions_id` and session cookie in browser points to new session.

Any ideas what could reset session?

This happens only in **production** environment. In development everything is fine.

Comment: Did you ever figure out your problem? I am having the same issue now. Doesn't really make sense :/

Comment: Well, I didn't figure out the problem, but the problem is gone somehow. It was strange. Did you try to delete session cookie and reload the page? Try and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is due to the call to `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token`; if the authenticity token is not verified, Rails will reset the session.  You also want to re-enable `protect_from_forgery`.

I've also seen AJAX requests without an authenticity token to cause the session to reset, again more detail here: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2011/11/17/i-saw-an-extremely-subtle-bug-today-and-i-just-have-to-tell-someone/

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11943243/449342

Comment: I removed `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token` and uncommented `protect_from_forgery` but the problem still persist.

Comment: The problem for the first place was that I had `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken` exeptions during POST request. Which is obvious, CSRF check are performed during POST requests. I have `authenticity_token` hidden field in my form, so it was not the issue. 

I still think that the issue is that session is reset after every request.