# Ruby on Rails Devise - Cannot Log Out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am a bit new to Ruby (v2.0.0) on Rails (v4.0.0) and Devise (v3.5.2), and for some reason I cannot Sign Out once I have Signed Up. However, if I manually go into the MySQL2 database and completely delete the user, my Sign Up/Sign In page becomes available again.

I have not touched my session_store.rb initializer or anything else. I am in dire straits and need this fixed before I can move forward.

Help is greatly appreciated.

The logic for my Sign Up form is very simple:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
    <%= current_user.email %> / <%= link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>
<% else %>
    <%= link_to "Sign Up", new_user_registration_path %> / <%= link_to "Log In", new_user_session_path %>
<% end %>
```

My **devise.rb** file is also configured to use :delete :

```
config.sign_out_via = :delete
```

I have **JQuery** in my **Gemfile**:

```
# jQuery
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
```

And I have them initialized in **application.js**:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.ui.all
//= require jquery.details
//= require jquery.textchange
```

My **routes.rb** is properly configured (the commented out "#devise_for :users" shows that I have tried both methods, none worked) :

```
Selfstarter::Application.routes.draw do
root :to => 'home#index'
  #devise_for :users
  devise_for :users do
  get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
  end
...
end
```

And my **rake routes** reflects that:

```
                  Prefix Verb     URI Pattern                     Controller#Action
                    root GET      /                               home#index
        new_user_session GET      /users/sign_in(.:format)        devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST     /users/sign_in(.:format)        devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE   /users/sign_out(.:format)       devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST     /users/password(.:format)       devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET      /users/password/new(.:format)   devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET      /users/password/edit(.:format)  devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH    /users/password(.:format)       devise/passwords#update
                         PUT      /users/password(.:format)       devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET      /users/cancel(.:format)         devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST     /users(.:format)                devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET      /users/sign_up(.:format)        devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET      /users/edit(.:format)           devise/registrations#edit
                         PATCH    /users(.:format)                devise/registrations#update
                         PUT      /users(.:format)                devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE   /users(.:format)                devise/registrations#destroy
```

**user.rb** Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

**database.rb** just in case it's needed:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: dbname
  pool: 5
  username: dbusername
  password: dbpass
  #socket: /opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock
```

I am at a loss as to what to what steps to take next, and have scoured Google and Stack Overflow. I found nothing.

I also want to mention that I would really want to stick to RESTful conventions, and would not like to use :get methods if at all possible.

**EDIT: My Log File**

```
Started DELETE "/users/sign_out" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-08-21 11:28:17 -0400
Started DELETE "/users/sign_out" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-08-21 11:28:17 -0400
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#destroy as HTML
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#destroy as HTML
  User Load (3.0ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  User Load (3.0ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
   (1.0ms)  BEGIN
   (1.0ms)  BEGIN
   (1.0ms)  COMMIT
   (1.0ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 66ms (ActiveRecord: 5.0ms)
Completed 302 Found in 66ms (ActiveRecord: 5.0ms)
```

Comment: post what you have in your logs while requesting logout link please

Comment: This is going to sound stupid but how do I access my log? My development.log file in my log directory is empty, and my command line loses lots of information when I preform an action because it scrolls down so much, so I can't see a whole lot.

Comment: Are you able to see the Sign Out link at all? If yes, like @Avdept mentionned, please post the logs when you request the logout link

Comment: Yes I am able to see my links Alexandre. See my above comment with my stupid log problem.

Comment: Just checking, but have you restarted your server after installing `Devise` and all that?

Comment: Yes I have restarted the server many times.

Also I have edited my log output at the bottom of my initial post.

Comment: See this question for CRSF token issues like that you're having: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11845500/rails-devise-authentication-csrf-issue

Comment: I have tried this already, it did not work unfortunately.

Comment: Also put your destroy action please.Its not clear whats happens there

Comment: Is there supposed to be a destroy action? I am using the Devise gem, I thought it was built into that, so I don't exactly have a Users controller.

Comment: Solved, answer is below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally discovered the solution.
I merely had to add `<%= csrf_meta_tags %>` into my **application.html.erb** header tags and it worked like a charm.